# Azure REST API get resource parentResourcePath parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

**Context**

I am willing to get a resource details with the Azure REST API. And more particularly, I want to get the IAM associated with a resource.

**Problem**

So, I searched in the doc reference and found that endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/get which provides an identity response attribute that meets my needs.

However, I can't find any information about the required path parameter `parentResourcePath`. What does that parameter mean and how can I get its value for a specific resource ?

Also, when I tried going through the resources group path, I can get a path to the resource details but without the `parentResourcePath` parameter, and the response doesn't include the identity attribute.

Finally, am I going the right way (using GET resource API) ? And if so, where can I find that `parentResourcePath` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have a better choice - [**Resources - Get By Id**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/getbyid).

The `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{parentResourcePath}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}` in the api  [`Resources - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/get) named `resourceId` which used in the `Resources - Get By Id`.

But if you combinate the properties manually, it is not easy, Azure has many different resource providers, resourcetype.

Generally, you could find the `resourceId` in your resource in the portal -> `Properties`. Also, the response of this API will include the `identity` which you need.

Sample:

Get a web app resource.

The `resourceId` is like `/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/joywebapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/joywebapp2`.

You can click `Try it` in the doc to try the api.

Response:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the `UserAssignedIdentities` property doesn't exist in the get Resources endpoint. Even though it's in the documentation

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Are you sure? Per my test, it also works. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGZlp.png

Comment: Yes, here's my output from the Get Resource endpoint: https://i.imgur.com/R8J3EHj.png

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Did you add your User Assigned Identity to your web app? In your web app in the portal -> Identity -> User assigned (preview) -> Add. If you don't bind them together, it will not appear in that.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I think you may not understand the usage of the managed identity, if you create a managed identity in the portal, it will create a service principal in your azure ad tenant automatically. If you want to use it with a web app, you need to add it like the steps above. If you just use it as a normal service principal, it only represents itself, not the web app.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it. I can't see any managed identity from the portal. But my question was more about fetching the IAM Access control associated to a resource. I am accepting this answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Well I made it throught the Role assignment list for scope endpoint, giving the subscription/resourcegroup/resource in the scope. And the output contains a principalId attribute that seems to point to a user or group or service principal.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforscope

Comment: This reply is not the same thing as your question at all. I think my reply is correct enough, could you accept it?